# Regex for a whole word in a string, that doesn't start with the dollar sign

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to match substrings that don't start with `$`. E.g. `b a b` should match, but `b $a b` shouldn't. I tried using:

```
/\b(?![$])a\b/
/\b(?!\$)a\b/
/\b(?=[^$])a\b/
```

but all match `b $a b`. I know I can `split` by whitespace, and use `str.starts_with? '$'` on each element, but I wonder why the regex doesn't work.

Edit: I'M looking for a regex such that:

```
'b $a b' =~ <regex>
=> nil
'b a b' =~ <regex>
=> 2
```

which will be used in `full_str.gsub(<regex>, 'c')` yielding:

```
'b a b'.gsub(<regex>, 'c')
=> 'b c b'
'b $a b'.gsub(<regex>, 'c')
=> 'b $a b'
'b a b $a b'.gsub(<regex>, 'c')
=> 'b c b $a b'
```

Comment: Since you changed the question, now Wiktor Stribiżew's answer looks a bit irrelevant.

Comment: @sawa: I can adjust my answer.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: Coudl you please specify what exact output you expect? Match the whole string if it has no word starting with `$`? Or match a string that has no `$a` word inside? Or you want to match `b` and `b` in `b $a b`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `'b $a b' =~ <regex>` => `nil`

Comment: It is because of `$a` or because of a word that starts with `$`?

Comment: just `$a` to keep things simple

Comment: `which will be used in full_str.gsub(<regex>, [..])` - what is the result you expect for your 2 inputs: 1) `b $a b` and 2) `b a b`? The current `'b a b' =~ /\b(?<!\$)a\b/` does not look quite helpful I think.

Comment: Since `$` is matched as word boundary, I would go with `/(?<!\s\$)\w+/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated

Comment: Ok, I used a similar input in my demo, see the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\b(?![$])a\b` (and `/\b(?!\$)a\b/` is an equivalent expression) matches a `a` in `$a` because the pattern matches any `a` enclosed with non-word characters or start/end of string and that is not `$` (and `a` cannot be `$`, thus the lookahead is always true here). The `\b(?=[^$])a\b` regex again matches an `a` in `$a` because this expression matches any `a` as a whole word (i.e. enclosed with non-word characters or start/end string) that is not equal to `$` (the `(?=[^$])` positive lookahead requires the next character to be anything but `$`, and as `a` is not `$`, the pattern returns `a` in `$a`).

Assuming you want to match a word `a` that is not preceded with `$`, use

```
'b a b' =~ /\b(?<!\$)a\b/
```

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\$)` will fail a match if the whole word `a` is preceded with `$` symbol.

See [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/zpPcrl):

```
puts 'b a b'.gsub(/\b(?<!\$)a\b/, "B")  # b B b
puts 'b $a b'.gsub(/\b(?<!\$)a\b/, "B") # b $a b
```

Comment: Anyway, my explanations of your current attempts were relevant from the beginning. sawa was wrong saying that my answer was "a bit irrelevant" after your edit.

Comment: I have adjusted the answer to show just the relevant information. All the rest (that now seems irrelevant) can be found in the change history.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: You can try the Regexp that Wiktor gave on http://rubular.com, it comes in very handy to see whats going on with your Regexp.

Comment: Yes, this regex will work in Ruby the same way as with PCRE. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC6zP8/1).